# Events not appearing when moving from an empty month

Tags: fullcalendar

If I move from a month with events to a month without events and then back again, my events are not re-appearing.  Moving between months with events is working fine.  I have to refresh the page to get them to come back.  Here is my code and I just cannot see anything wrong...

```
$("#datepicker").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left:   'prev,next,cbRefresh',
                center: 'title',
                right:  ''
            },
            height:             750,
            firstDay:           1,
            weekNumbers:        true,
            editable:           false,
            eventLimit:         true,
            displayEventTime:   false,
            dayClick: function(seldate,jsEvent,view) {
                window.location.href="multiple?dt="+seldate.format();
            },
            eventClick: function(evt,jsEvent,view) {
                if(evt.id) {
                    window.location.href="details?id="+evt.id+"&dt="+evt.start.format();
                }
            },
            events: {
                    url:    servicePath+"calendar.php",
                    type:   'GET',
                    data:   function() {

                            var theDate=$("#datepicker").fullCalendar('getDate');
                            return {
                                t:      'load',
                                uid:    uid,
                                mon:    theDate.month()+1
                            }
                },
                error:  function(){
                    displayError("Events error: " +item.ErrorMessage);
                }
            },
            eventRender: function(evt,ele,view) {
                $(ele).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr("data-num",evt.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $(this).attr("data-worked",evt.worked);
                    $(".fc-title",this).attr("title",evt.activity);                     
                });
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {

                if(view.name=="month") {

                    for(cDay=view.start.clone(); cDay.isBefore(view.end); cDay.add(1,'day')) {
                        var ttl=0;
                        var dateNum=cDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        $(".fc-event-container").find('.fc-event[data-num="'+dateNum+'"]').each(function(){

                            var currentWorked=$(this).attr("data-worked");
                            if(currentWorked) {
                                ttl+=parseInt(currentWorked);
                            }

                        });

                        //display the total and relevant buttons
                        if(ttl>0) {

                            var footer=$('.fc-day[data-date="'+dateNum+'"]').find(".fc-cell-footer");

                            $(footer).append('<a title="Delete all" class="btn btn-xs" href="delete?dt='+dateNum+'">'+
                                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>'+
                                            '<a title="Copy" class="btn btn-xs" href="copy?dt='+dateNum+'">'+
                                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span></a>'+
                                            '<a title="List" class="btn btn-xs" href="list?dt='+dateNum+'">'+
                                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>');
                            $(footer).append('<span class="ttlHours">Hours: '+buildTime(ttl)+'</span>');
                        }

                    }

                }

            },
            dayRender: function(date,cell) {

                var theDate=moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                $(cell).css("vertical-align", "bottom"); 
                $(cell).append('<div class="fc-cell-footer"></div>');
            },
            customButtons: {
                cbRefresh: {
                    text:   'Refresh',
                    click:  function() {
                        $("#datepicker").fullCalendar("destroy");
                        buildCalendar();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Have even tried stripping the code back to the very basics and still not working. I do know the 'events: data' is being fired every time as I have it set to email me (while testing).

```
        $("#datepicker").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left:   'prev,next,cbRefresh',
                center: 'title',
                right:  ''
            },
            height:             750,
            firstDay:           1,
            weekNumbers:        true,
            editable:           true,
            eventLimit:         true,
            displayEventTime:   false,

            events: {
                    url:    servicePath+"calendar.php",
                    type:   'GET',
                    data:   function() {

                            var theDate=$("#datepicker").fullCalendar('getDate');
                            return {
                                t:      'load',
                                uid:    uid,
                                mon:    theDate.month()+1
                            }
                },
                error:  function(){
                    displayError("Events error: " +item.ErrorMessage);
                }
            },
            customButtons: {
                cbRefresh: {
                    text:   'Refresh',
                    click:  function() {
                        $("#datepicker").fullCalendar("destroy");
                        buildCalendar();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the URL you provide is filtering on the events that the calendar should show. Try something simple as:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        events: {
          url: 'getcalendar.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
          },
          success : function(response){
            console.log("Updated events: "+response.length);
          }
        }
});
```

Php:

```
<?php
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $query = mysqli(X,"SELECT * FROM calendar startdate >= '$start' AND enddate <= '$end'");
    echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC));
?>
```

Comment: no nothing to do with the actual data base work as I know this is firing and returning the correct data, as it is emailing me the SQL statement every time (while I test it). When I start up the calendar has events for July and shows them, I then move to august which has no events.  I go back to July and nothing shows up, but the sql is correct